# How can I manage an exception generated by Postgis?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, exception

I am running the following query on Postgres 10.3/Postgis 2.4:

```
create table table_c as (
    select A.*, B.area_name, B.id
    from table_a A
    left join table_b B
    on ST_Contains(A.geom, B.geom)
);
```

that fails with a cryptic:

```
ERROR:  GEOSContains: TopologyException: side location conflict at -2.0889721121124643 53.528652265475735
```

due to Postgis (and relative used libraries).

Is there a way to skip exceptional cases and keeping the query running until finished?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the select are totally useless.

Comment: I know it thanks :) but I think they are more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is filtering the query or prefixing the data using commands like:

ST_IsValidReason, ST_IsValid, ST_MakeValid.

http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_IsValidReason.html

Comment: Yes, `ST_IsValid()` should serve well! Wrap (only!) the table with (possibly) violating values in a subquery with `WHERE ST_IsValid(geom))`, then the index on the other table should still be usable.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the PostGIS function `ST_Contains()` in a plpgsql (or other PL) function of your own and [trap the exception](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) there. Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_ST_Contains(geometry, geometry)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN ST_Contains($1,$2);

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   RETURN FALSE;  -- Return FALSE instead of raising an exception
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

This returns `FALSE` instead of raising an error. You might want return `NULL` instead. Same effect on your query.

And use that instead of `ST_Contains()` in your query:

```
...
ON f_ST_Contains(A.geom, B.geom)
```

Schema-qualify the function name in the function definition (and in the call) to remove dependency on the search path:

```
...
RETURN public.ST_Contains($1,$2);  -- actual schema of extension here
...
```

Not sure about implications on performance (especially index usage); didn't test.

Comment: Thank you, it is a nice solution. Unfortunately the query planner in "explain" looks like it is skipping the indexes.

Comment: let's try with geography columns

Comment: I have added my answer