# COALESCE with cast

Tags: postgresql, null, cast, coalesce, empty-string

I'm pulling data from a `jsonb` column in Postgres, and casting it to an `integer` to compare it against a count. The problem is that in some cases the data apparently can't be cast to `integer` and I get:

> ```
> SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
> ```

I've tried both of these, and they both work for the first 400-500 rows until it hits a row with bad data:

```
select coalesce(CAST(raw_record->>'ObjectCount' AS integer), 0) from resources 
where record_id = '274015000000'

select CAST(raw_record->>'ObjectCount' AS integer) from resources 
where record_id = '274015000000'
```

Is there a way to fall back to `0` if the cast doesn't work?

Comment: Could you add some sample data, just to check what are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NULLIF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF), like you already found:

```
SELECT NULLIF(raw_record->>'ObjectCount','')::int ...
```

.. to replace the empty string with NULL. Strictly speaking, your question asks for more:

> Is there a way to fall back to `0` if the cast doesn't work?

A more general solution:

- [How can I manage an exception generated by Postgis?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204795/how-can-i-manage-an-exception-generated-by-postgis/204808#204808)

[`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) is unrelated to the question. But adapt slightly what you have in your answer to reduce casting back and forth:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(raw_record->>'ObjectCount','')::int, 0) ...
```

It should be a bit faster to replace both functions with [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN raw_record->>'ObjectCount' <> ''  -- excludes null and ''
            THEN (raw_record->>'ObjectCount')::int
            ELSE 0 END ...
```

Related:

- [Best way to check for “empty or null value”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)

Answer (score 2):

I was on the right track but the wrong train. Here's what ended up working:

```
select COALESCE(NULLIF(raw_record->>'ObjectCount',''),0)::int 
from resources where record_id = '274015000000'
```